# Display highest value and index number in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have one method which used to display the highest value and also display which index number it belongs to. So far it already can display the highest value but the index number  cannot be displayed. What should I do so that the system can display the `i` value also?

```
private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray(); 
    double highest=Double.MIN_VALUE;

    System.out.println(highest);
    for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++)
    {
        if(aa[i]>highest)
        {
            highest=aa[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(highest);
    System.out.println(i); // Error: create local variable i
}
```

Comment: You can print inside your if condition :)

Comment: You have to declare your variable above your for loop

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ that would print the index of the *currently* highest number each time, and not the index of the "global" max.

Comment: @vefthym just try it ;)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I don't need to try it... if `aa` is `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]`, then it would print 0, then 1, then 2, and finally 3, right? Unless I misunderstood your suggestion... I suppose that the OP is asking to print `i=3` only, as the maximum value (4.0) is at index 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to modify your code to save the max AND `i`:

```
private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray(); 
    double highest=Double.MIN_VALUE;
    int index=0;
    System.out.println(highest);
    for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++)
    {
        if(aa[i]>highest)
        {
            index=i;
            highest=aa[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(highest);
    System.out.println(index); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's what I'm looking for

Comment: @user5156075 if this is the solution, as you say, then please accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

You need one more variable to store the index of highest variable.

```
int highestIndex = 0;//Store index at some other variable
for(int i=0; i< aa.length; i++) {
     if(aa[i] > highest) {
         highest = aa[i];
         highestIndex  = i;
     }
}
System.out.println("Highest value :"+highest+ " found at index :"+highestIndex);
```

Comment: This code will not display highest value, It will display first value which is higher than `Double.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the index of the highest value too:

```
private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray(); 
    double highest=Double.MIN_VALUE;
    int highestIndex;

    System.out.println(highest);
    for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++)
    {
        if(aa[i]>highest)
        {
            highest=aa[i];
            highestIndex=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(highest);
    System.out.println(highestIndex); // Error: create local variablre i
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but u forgot to initialize the highestIndex